# Auto populate 2 dropdowns (fed with AJAX) in a row, with value in session. First one triggering the second

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, session

Good day to you all,

I have two dropdowns on a form, where the values in the second are populated from the selection made in the first one. For retaining the value on form reload, the values in the first dropdown are populated on load, but the `onchange` event does not get triggered (it works when I manually select the value from the first dropdown), hence the second dropdown is not auto populated.

The values to be selected in both dropdowns are present in the session.

Summary -

- Populate 1st drop down, on reoad -> done
- select its previous value stored in session -> done
- load the values in the second dropdown, based on the 1st selection ->
  pending  :(
- select the value of the second drop down in session -> pending  :(

I am kinda stuck, can someone suggest something? By the way, I am using PHP and jQuery.

Basically, on an accidental page reload, the drop downs must get populated like dominos falling on each other, tish tish tish,, the values for each of them are available in session,(saved before the reload)

Comment: Show your tried code. *Pending*

Comment: numerous plugins for this... google `jquery cascade select`

Comment: well, i am done with the cascade select, when you manually select the drop downs .. the next ones in the series get populated. The issue is, when i have to populate each one automatically, say on some accidental page reload, if the values for each drop down are saved in the session.

Comment: You can just manually trigger the `change` event on the first select when it's already populated: `document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].onchange();`

Comment: well i ve tried a similar thing by selecting Id of the `SELECT` tag, but it gives me an error : `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onchange' of object #<HTMLSelectElement> is not a function`

Comment: @Pioul Hi Pioul, your answered worked, please put it in the answers, then i ll be able to accept it

Comment: Well instead of selecting by Tagname(which can lead into an infinite loop), you could sugget to do it by Id,

Comment: @Archer I followed your proposition and added `getElementById` to the answer since it's another correct way of doing it, but I never heard of the issue you're talking about, what's your source?

Comment: @Pioul well, my source is ajax fetching from the database, but the error was due to the last drop down in the series, it had no onchange function specified. Now i have added a `javascript:void(0)` to it, hence it is ok, Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually trigger the `change` event on the first select when it's already populated:

```
// trigger onchange on the first select in the page
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].onchange();

// trigger onchange on #theselect
document.getElementById("theselect").onchange();
```